# $P(A\cup B) = 5/6, P(AB) = 5/6$, $A,B$ are independent, find $P(A)$.

Tags: probability

Here is the question. $P(A\cup B) = 5/6, P(AB) = 5/6$, $A,B$ are independent. Find $P(A)$.

My solution is $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B) - P(AB) = 5/6$, which means $P(A) + P(B) = 10/6$. Insert it into $P(AB) = P(A)P(B) = 5/6$, we get $ P(A)(10/6 - P(A)) = 5/6$, and finally
$ 10 P(A) - 6 P(A)^2 = 5$. Clearly, this equation does not have a real solution.

So what is the problem? Is there anything wrong in my solution, or is there any mistake in the question? I could not figure out, please give me some advice.

Comment: You have not done anything wrong. Such events $A$ and $B$ do not exist!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem. Notice that : $\mathbb{P}(AB) \le \min(\mathbb{P}(A), \mathbb{P}(B))$. Then $\mathbb{P}(A)) \ge 5/6$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)) \ge 5/6$. Which is incompatible with $\mathbb{P}(AB) = \mathbb{P}(A) \times \mathbb{P}(B) = 5/6$

Comment: Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 2):

It is

$$P(A)+P(B)= \frac{5}{3}$$

and

$$P(A)P(B)=\frac{5}{6}\Rightarrow P(B)=\frac{5}{6P(A)}$$

and hence

$$P(A) + \frac{5}{6P(A)}=\frac{5}{3}\Rightarrow 6(P(A))^2-10P(A)+5=0$$

Set $P(A)=\omega\geq 0$ and thus

$$6\omega^2 - 10\omega +5 = 0$$

and

$$\Delta= 100 - 120 =-20<0$$ in other words there are no events $A$ and $B$ independent such that it holds $P(A)+P(B)=5/3$ and $P(AB)=5/6$...Nothing is wrong...

In case you want such events to exist, re-adjust the numbers, so as the trinomial would have a solution in $\mathbb{R}$ and more specifically in $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it!